# In ConnectionFactory.php line 274: Class 'Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection' not found

Tags: mysql, laravel

I try to find many way to connect mysql with laravel framework but when I install it already it show error like this: 
[image]
After run php artisan serve:

In ConnectionFactory.php line 274:

Class 'Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection' not found

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever run success php artisan? If not, It seems like your composer is not working. You could try reinstall laravel. Hope will solve your problem.

Comment: Yes I use to run php artisan successful, but after I installed mysql it show like this.

Comment: Maybe your mysql configuration is wrong, check mysql configuration in config/database.php or .env